# Exporting Live data from metatrader 4 to text file

Tags: text-files, export-to-csv, live, metatrader4

I know how to export historical data from mt4, but what if I need live tick data?

How to program an EA for mt4 to export tick data to a txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at 
http://docs.mql4.com/files
and
http://docs.mql4.com/predefined/variables

Set up a loop with short sleep and write ask/bid to file if changed